# Will an EU medical degree be recognised in another EU country?

Tags: eu, qualifications

If I have a medical degree from a EU country, let say Bulgaria, can I work as a doctor in another EU country? Which qualifications will be recognised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work as a doctor in another EU country, you must apply to the authority that oversees the doctor profession in that country, providing proof of your qualifications.

Basic medical training and general practitioner training are automatically recognised throughout the EU, entitling you to work in any EU country, if they are listed in respectively Annex V, points [5.1.1](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/qualifications/docs/future/annexe-v-1-1-basic-medical-training_en.xls) and [5.1.4](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/qualifications/docs/future/annexe-v-1-4-gp_en.xls) of the Directive 2005/36/EC, which are conform to Art. 24 or 28 of the Directive, or benefit from acquired rights.

Some specialist doctors’ qualifications are automatically recognised in certain EU countries. These are listed in [Annexes V, point 5.1](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/qualifications/policy_developments/legislation/index_en.htm#annexes) of the Directive on recognition of professional qualifications.
All of the countries listed for each given field will automatically recognise each others’ qualifications in that field.

Even if your qualification does not meet the automatic criteria for recognition, it may still be recognised in another EU country, under the general system for recognition of qualifications. See article 10 to 15 of the Directive.
If there are major differences between the qualifications you have from your home country and the qualifications required to work in the EU country where you want to work, you may be asked to sit an aptitude test to check that you have the skills required in your chosen country or complete an adaptation period.

For more information visit [europe.eu](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/qualifications/directive_in_practice/automatic_recognition/doctors/index_en.htm)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Dutch association of medical doctors (KNMG) the answer is [yes](http://knmg.artsennet.nl/Diensten/Beroepskeuze/Wet-en-regelgeving-2/Buitenlands-gediplomeerden/Procedures/Buitenlandse-artsen-van-binnen-de-EU.htm) (link is in dutch).

There is however a but... You need to register with the local authorities and register according to the local regulations. In case of the Netherlands that means that your medical degree is recognised, not automatically your specialisation. In the Netherlands this is called "basisarts" or basic doctor. To practice a specific specialisation you need to contact the relevant professional organisation.

Note that in the Netherlands a general practitioner is considered a specialist too and a such you will need to contact their professional association as well.

I assume these regulations are similar in other EU countries.